# Why does node.js don't find the function if the files requires each other

Tags: node.js

Here is my situation:

- file a.js require file b.js
- file b.js require file a.js

When I try to call a function which is in file b.js from file a.js then I get the exception that `b.xy() is not a function`.

If I remove the require in file b.js then node.js can find the function.

Why does node.js don't find the function if the files requires 
each other?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles

Comment: have you exported the function in b module like this: module.exports = xy;

Comment: @shaahin - Of course